# Unable to change the default download location of chrome in AWS lambda to /tmp using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am unable to change the default download location of chrome in AWS lambda to /tmp.

I am automating a website using selenium which basically downloads a .xls file from the website to "desired location" when running locally in mac or windows, but don't know where it is downloading in aws lambda headless mode.

**I want to store/download the file to /tmp location while clicking on the download button while automation**

**The code below is working in local, but on AWS Lambda it's not working**

```
    os.system(f"mkdir -p /tmp")
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": file_path}
    opt = Options()
    opt.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    opt.add_argument('--headless')
    opt.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    opt.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=os.environ.get('DRIVER'), chrome_options=opt)
    driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = (
    "POST",
    "/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command",
    )
    params = {
        "cmd": "Page.setDownloadBehavior",
        "params": {"behavior": "allow", "downloadPath": '/tmp'},
    }
    data = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Lambda /tmp Download Path:

Had the same configuration with Lambda. The following options worked for me:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"browser.downloads.dir": "//tmp//", "download.default_directory": "//tmp//", "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```