# Download file to AWS Lambda /tmp file directory using Chromedriver

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate the download of a file to the /tmp directory in AWS Lambda using Chromedriver from this website https://registry.verra.org/app/search/VCS/All%20Projects. The steps are to 1) click on the 'Search' button, 2) wait for the results to load, 3) click on the 'Excel' logo to download the file.

I've referenced and tried the code provided in these 2 questions to change the download directory of Chromedriver but the file is not downloaded in the /tmp path.

[AWS Lambda download a file using Chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73395376/aws-lambda-download-a-file-using-chromedriver/74623579#74623579)

```
prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.default_directory": r"/tmp",
    "directory_upgrade": True
    }
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

[Unable to change the default download location of chrome in AWS lambda to /tmp using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777965/unable-to-change-the-default-download-location-of-chrome-in-aws-lambda-to-tmp-u)

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"browser.downloads.dir": "//tmp//", "download.default_directory": "//tmp//", "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

For reference, here is my code which works fine in local but not in AWS Lambda.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os
import requests 
import requests.auth
import json
import csv

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # change directory to /tmp folder
    os.chdir('/tmp')
    
    # get dataset from website
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        
    ## SAVE TO TMP DIRECTORY
    # set download settings
    prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.default_directory": r"/tmp",
    "directory_upgrade": True
    }
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    
    
    ## open Chrome webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver',options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('https://registry.verra.org/app/search/VCS/All%20Projects')


    # wait for 60 seconds for website content to load
    print("Waiting for website to load...")
    element1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/apx-root/div/div/apx-search-page/div/apx-search-container/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/apx-search-selection-criteria/div/form/div[2]/div/button[1]')))
    print("Website loaded!")

    # click on search button to load results
    search_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/apx-root/div/div/apx-search-page/div/apx-search-container/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/apx-search-selection-criteria/div/form/div[2]/div/button[1]')
    search_btn.click()

    # wait for results to load for 100 seconds - determine by checking the page numbers
    element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/apx-root/div/div/apx-search-page/div/apx-search-container/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/apx-project-search-results/div/div/kendo-grid/kendo-pager/kendo-pager-numeric-buttons/ul/li[1]/a')))
    print("Results loaded!")

    # wait for download button to load for 100 seconds - determine by detecting presence of download button
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/apx-root/div/div/apx-search-page/div/apx-search-container/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/apx-project-search-results/div/apx-search-results-header/div/button[1]')))
    download_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/apx-root/div/div/apx-search-page/div/apx-search-container/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/apx-project-search-results/div/apx-search-results-header/div/button[1]')
    
    # click on download button
    # if element is not clickable
    filepath = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    
    # wait for 60 seconds for file to download
    time.sleep(60)
    
    
    # check if file is downloaded to /tmp directory
    # Method 2   
    list = os.listdir('/tmp')
    print("list", list)

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "Selenium Headless Chrome Initialized"
    }
    
    return response
```

Could this be a versioning issue? Because my code only works if the runtime settings is for Python 3.7.

**Selenium version:** selenium/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages selenium==3.8.0\ (runtime Python 3.7)

**Chromedriver version:** [https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip\](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip%5C) (only runtime Python 3.9 works, changing to Python 3.7 does not work)

**Headless Chrome:** https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-41/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip

Comment: Sometimes I find stuff in Lambdas where you are trying to execute against the container can be unpredictable if there are environmental blocks etc. Might be easier to do this all in a Dockerised lambda instead? Do you even have to download to disk rather than memory?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found the answer following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777965/unable-to-change-the-default-download-location-of-chrome-in-aws-lambda-to-tmp-u).
Apparently there is a difference in how the chromedriver treats downloads that are initiated by a POST request generated from a button click.

Adding the following code fixed my problem:

```
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = (
"POST",
"/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command",
)
params = {
    "cmd": "Page.setDownloadBehavior",
    "params": {"behavior": "allow", "downloadPath": '/tmp'},
}
data = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

Hope this helps!